# Routing + DS with ember-1.0.0-rc.1 + ember.data-11 [demo + tutorial + source]

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Where can I find a tutorial + demo + source to the latest ember-1.0.0-rc.1 + ember.data-11 version? Starter-Level.

I tried so many tutorials, but all I found are out dated :(

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example is worth taking a look at. It is very up to date and intends to provide a complete end-to-end example of using ember and ember-data backed by a simple Rails 3.2 app

Answer (score 0):

The ember docs and dev source have been the only definitive source of information for me, but the official examples are still being updated to work properly. Ember data is even further out of reach - heed their warning on the faq and don't use it for production.

As mentioned, there is a very well done peepcode video but it was released just weeks before the massive RC1 changes and so much it will only work if you use the pre-RC1 library. I can't imagine the peepcode producers are very pleased about having their training become almost completely obsolete so quickly.

At least RC1 should be the last major change that breaks everything, so try to move forward and not back.

Comment: I've walked through the Peepcode stuff and there's actually very little that breaks when upgrading from pre4 to rc1...at least as far as the stuff that the screencast shows you.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is definitely: http://trek.github.com/ for all of the detail it goes into. I suggest you sit down and read that, with a nice cup of coffee on the side to keep you going.

Comment: This is good reading, but it was written before the new Router API. The [Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/) is the most current resource.